# Laravel unique indexing

Tags: laravel, indexing, unique

I am starting to implement an import feature so i have created a new import table and model which has a film id and a user id and a url which belongs to a feed but i have a question and im unsure on the answer considering i dont have much experience with unique indexing.

**Migration**

```
  /**
 * Run the migrations.
 *
 * @return void
 */
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('imports', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->uuid('id')->primary();
        $table->string('feed_url')->unique();
        $table->string('email')->unique();
        $table->uuid('user_id')->unique();
        $table->uuid('film_id');
    });
}
```

If 2 different users wanted to import the exact same feed would these uniques i set allow that or not?

Comment: your `feed_url` is unique, it means that table can have only one unique value

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> If 2 different users wanted to import the exact same feed would these uniques i set allow that or not?

No it wouldn't. Don't use unique.

```
$table->string('feed_url');
```

Unique attribute instructs database that value must be distinct on entire column, regardless of what other columns contain.

---

As sidenote, avoid using indexes (INDEX, UNIQUE, PRIMARY) on string (VARCHAR, TEXT, ...) columns as they affect performance on large data.

Comment: what if i was to add an email to my edited question above or will these extra fields with uniques be irrelevant to my question above?

Comment: Unique attribute instructs database that value must be distinct on **entire column**.

Comment: Suppose you have a table with column `feed_url` is `UNIQUE`

Comment: And you insert a row where `feed_url` = 'www.google.com'

Comment: You are no longer allowed to insert another row with `feed_url` = 'www.google.com'

Comment: The same applies to all columns which have `UNIQUE` attribute.

Comment: ah okay so the same would apply with any unique i add to the column e.g if i inserted an email `test@example.com` i wouldnt be allowed to insert another

Comment: Yes. &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;